# How to create a group of sprites in flashpunk?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How to create a group or a layer with more than one sprites in Flashpunk?
Is there a class built in? If not, which class is suggested to be extended?

Comment: flashpunk.net but the official site is down. People who use it will know it.

Comment: @AbbyChauYuHoi Try looking through this: http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/games/an-introduction-to-flashpunk-the-basics/

Comment: i have been reading this but I guess it can only add one graphic per entity and the only way is doing all the logic in the world by looping the entities from getType("Xx"). However, more complex game engines like cocos2d-x seem to be supporting group or layer which can be controlled in both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign more than one graphic to an entity/layer via a graphiclist:

```
layer = -1;
var display:Graphiclist = new Graphiclist(buttonBackround,label,etc);
graphic = display;
```

You can also add a graphiclist in a world using

```
addGraphic(display,layerHere);
```

Just be sure to list items in the order you want them to be rendered in that layer, like a button's image before the label for example.

Hope that helps!

Comment: how about if I want to add a text?

Comment: Text will work as well, as long as it's classified as a graphic object (spritemap, image, tilemap, text, backdrop etc), you can add it to the graphic list.